# how to display long text on mobile website

Tags: mobile, html, scrolling, text

I trying to display a 2 page long page in a mobile website, i tried text area option but the scroll bars are not getting displayed in iphone mobile web. What are the ways you can think of for displaying a long page and options in the end if that page. What i can think of is pagination and what else are there ?

Comment: I think this is relevant [What affords scrolling?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/what-affords-scrolling)

Comment: Just to be clear, in what direction is the long text overflowing? Upwards / downwards or left / right?

Comment: it is top to bottom kind of scrolling . .

Answer (score 1):

Though you're displaying text, you might look at adding a graphical element like a patterned vertical line that runs alongside the text. The cut-off of the pattern can suggest that there's more, taking the place of the scroll bars that don't show up.

Alternately, you can design for an iPhone-sized screen and offer a next/previous page control. That might load a second page or just jump down/up in response, but it would make clear when the person is at the end of the text and when there is more to read.

Answer (score 1):

Have you confirmed with anyone using your app / site that this is even a problem yet?

I read many long articles on my phone and have never considered it a problem, even without a scroll bar.  The Economist app is an example of this.  I know I'm at the end when I try scroll and there isn't anything more.

If it's **really** a problem for you, you could use something like the slider on the Kindle app for both navigation and position feedback but you would run into other problems determining the position.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the footers on mobile websites stuck to the bottom of the browser. So as you scroll down the page, the footer sticks to the bottom of the browser.

However, I have never seen it work without lag when you're scrolling - which is really annoying and not a great experience.